# Маска изображения в виде трапеции

Tags: css

Задача - вставить несколько (4-5) картинок с маской в виде трапеции
(первое и последнее изображения обрезаются немного иначе, чем средние 2-3)
[image: задача]

Делаем:

HTML

```
<div class="imgs">
    <div class="img"><img src="/img/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="img">....
</div>
```

LESS

```
.imgs {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    height: 20vw;
    min-height: 110px;
    max-height: 300px;
    margin-left: -50px;

    .img {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .7;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: skew(25deg);

        img {
            transform: skew(-25deg) scale(1.5);
            height: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        &:hover {
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 1;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #000;
        }

        &:first-child {margin-left: -6%}
        &:last-child {margin-right: -6%}
    }
}
```

Получается в целом нормально но печалит необходимость увеличивать картинку в 1.5 раза, иначе у нее остаются черные поля - в начале деформируется рамка, потом картина обрезается, а потом выравнивается:
[image: фото без увеличения]

Как обрезать изображения по нужной форме и при этом не увеличивать их? Спасибо

Comment: https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/ вот здесь легко нарисовать любую фигуру в CSS

Comment: Да, отличный совет, большое спасибо! Оформите ответом - закрою вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот здесь](https://cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator) легко нарисовать любую фигуру в CSS!